# Как привязать конкретное дейтвие к виджетам QLabel, которые создаются в цикле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qlabel

Я создал два файла **Design.py** и **Main.py**. 
В **Design.py** находится класс `Label()`, единственный метод, которого создает и возвращает виджет `QLabel`, содержащий скругленное изображение. Фактически данный код не принадлежит мне - это объясняет то, что он работает:)

Я оставлю его тут, на всякий случай:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Label:
    def create_label(self, picture):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.label.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.label.width(), self.label.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.target)
        return self.label
```

---

Мой вопроc касается файла **Main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import Design

list_ = ['1', '2', '3']

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.LabelCopy = Design.Label()
        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.box1)
        self.create_label()
    
    def create_label(self):
        for i in list_:
            self.label = self.LabelCopy.create_label('picture2.png')
            self.box1.addWidget(self.label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Здесь у меня есть список **`list_`**. Для упрощения вопроса я наполнил его тремя цифрами и теперь хотел для каждой цифры создать `QLabel`, воспользовавшись методом **`create_label()`** класса `Label()`, что находится в том самом файле **Design.py**.

К этим виджетам я хотел привязать функции, которые будут выводить в консоль соответсвующую цифру.
Т.е. чтобы `QLabel`, созданный в цикле первым, печатал первый элемент списка, второй `QLabel` - второй элемент списка и т.д.

К сожалению, будучи очень ограниченным своих знаниях, я уже сижу час и не понимаю, как тут применить **`pyqtSignal()`** и **`mousePressEvent()`**.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как реализовать выше описанное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Когда вы создаете `label` - наследуйте от `QLabel`
2. в `classe Label` - создаем сигнал `clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)`, который в качестве параметра передаст строку
3. в методе `mouseReleaseEvent` - имитируем испускание сигнала `self.clicked.emit(self.num)`
4. в цикле создаем экземпляры `label = Label('head3.png', i)`
5. делаем привязку экземпляр-сигнал-слот `label.clicked.connect(lambda num=i: self.onClicked(num))` с передачей в слот строки из списка.
6. не надо использовать `list_` как глобальную переменную.
7. в слоте `def onClicked(self, value)` печатаем то, что вы хотели.

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

#import Design
#class Label:
#    def create_label(self, picture):
class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)                             # +++   1

    def __init__(self, picture, num, *args, **kwargs):           # + picture, num 
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #print(f'picture->{picture} - {num}')
        self.num = num                                           # +

#        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()                         # убрал все self.label,
        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)                            # оставил self
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

#        return self.label

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):                               # +++ 
        self.clicked.emit(self.num)                                   # +++   2


#list_ = ['1', '2', '3']

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.list_ = ['1', '2', '3']                                    # +

#        self.LabelCopy = Design.Label()
#        self.LabelCopy = Label()

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
#        self.setLayout(self.box1)

#        self.create_label()
#    def create_label(self):
#        for i in self.list_:
#            self.label = self.LabelCopy.create_label('head3.png')
#            self.box1.addWidget(self.label)

# ++ VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
        for i in self.list_:
            label = Label('head3.png', i)                                # + i !!! Внимание
            label.clicked.connect(lambda num=i: self.onClicked(num))     # + 3
            self.box1.addWidget(label)

    def onClicked(self, value):                                          # +++
        print(f'value->{value}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хотел вам сказать большое человеческое спасибо. Частенько, когда я задавал вопросы на других ресурсах, встречал агрессивную критику, подкрепленную горячими эпитетами, и не понимал, что от меня хотят. Поэтому я очень удивлен, что есть люди, которые могут писать такие развернутые ответы:)

Comment: @MAXIM045 вы через 'надцать' месяцев, когда окрепните, не забудьте оказывать помощь, тому кто в ней нуждается. А те о ком вы пишите, это они от слабости, не обращайте внимание.

Comment: @MAXIM045 да, забыл сказать, что одной из ключевых особенностей Qt является использование сигналов и слотов для связи между объектами. https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html - это надо знать и понимать.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо:)

Comment: Сижу, разбираю код. Я уже не первый раз вижу у вас в коде элементы в фигурных скобках - {...}. Не подскажете, где почитать об этом? Просто я не знаю, как это называется

Comment: @MAXIM045   Интерполяция строк / f-Строки (Python 3.6+)  https://python-scripts.com/string-formatting#f-strings

Comment: Понял, спасибо!